# 2010s Point & Click Pc Game

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I played this game on a netbook around 2008-2014. The layout is similar to [*Stranded Sails*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/943260/Stranded_Sails__Explorers_of_the_Cursed_Islands/). The character is a warrior(?), and you point & click to move or interact. It involves various NPCs of witches, alchemists, and non-aggressive monsters. The setting is at night in the middle of a forest (not really sure if it was a forest) where you can find a small graveyard after a bit of walk; overall the scene is kind of gloomy. I remember the cursor is a hand with a brown gloves or armor. I can't indicate any more detail since I wasn't even sure how you were supposed to play it.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Diablo 3?

The first act is mostly played during night, is played in an isometric view, and the ascetic is gloomy.

> It was released for Microsoft Windows and OS X in May 2012, PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 in September 2013, PlayStation 4 and Xbox One in August 2014, and Nintendo Switch in November 2018. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_III)

The cursor could change depending on what you were pointing at on the screen, when hovering over a chest it is an armored hand.

Youtube walkthrough video of Act 1 - Gameplay starts at 3 minutes.

Comment: Probably not on a netbook.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer but this is not the game i looked for. Also as stated by SDH this game won't run on a netbook. I also forgot to state that the artstyle of the game i looked for was somewhat cartoonish.